# append currentChar to the end of cryptText, saving the result back to cryptText

Tags: java, string, append

```
package edu.westga.secretcode;

import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 * Creates the secret code class.
 * 
 * @author Stephen Roland
 * 
 */
public class SecretCode {
    /**
     * Perform the ROT13 operation
     * 
     * @param plainText
     *            the text to encode
     * @return the rot13'd encoding of plainText
     */

    public static String rotate13(String plainText) {
        String cryptText = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < plainText.length() - 1; i++) {
            char currentChar = plainText.charAt(i);
            currentChar += 13;
            cryptText.append(currentChar);


        }
        return cryptText;

    }

    /**
     * Main method of the SecretCode class
     * 
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (1 > 0) {
            System.out.println("Enter plain text to encode, or QUIT to end");
            Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
            String plainText = keyboard.nextLine();
            if (plainText.equals("QUIT")) {
                break;
            }
            String cryptText = SecretCode.rotate13(plainText);
            String encodedText = SecretCode.rotate13(plainText);

            System.out.println("Encoded Text: " + encodedText);
        }

    }

}
```

Hey guys I have a simple question. As the question states it says to append currentChar to the end of cryptText, saving the result back to cryptText. What I have did is this in the for loop and it is not working: cryptText.append(currentChar); This seems pretty simple but after researching this for an hour I am stuck. Any help would be greatly appreciated as to how to do this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: cryptText is String and there is no append method in String

Comment: It ask me to append currentChar to the end of cryptText, saving the result back to cryptText, so what should I do to do this.  I have been stuck on this for a while.  Thanks for any advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 * Creates the secret code class.
 * 
 * @author Stephen Roland
 * 
 */
 class SecretCode {
    /**
     * Perform the ROT13 operation
     * 
     * @param plainText
     *            the text to encode
     * @return the rot13'd encoding of plainText
     */

    public static String rotate13(String plainText) {
        StringBuffer cryptText = new StringBuffer("");
        for (int i = 0; i < plainText.length(); i++) {
            char currentChar = plainText.charAt(i);
            currentChar = (char)((char)(currentChar-'A' + 13)%26 + 'A');
            cryptText.append(currentChar);


        }
        return cryptText.toString();

    }

    /**
     * Main method of the SecretCode class
     * 
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (1 > 0) {
            System.out.println("Enter plain text to encode, or QUIT to end");
            Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
            String plainText = keyboard.nextLine();
            if (plainText.equals("QUIT")) {
                break;
            }
            //String cryptText = SecretCode.rotate13(plainText);
            String encodedText = SecretCode.rotate13(plainText);

            System.out.println("Encoded Text: " + encodedText);
        }

    }

}
```